# Getting multiple files value by javascript or jquery is not working properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I am trying to send images on server using jquery and ajax method. I want to upload multiple files but I am not able to get it properly.

My html codes,

```
<input type="file" name="imgs" multiple class="form-control floating-label" placeholder="">
```

my jquery codes,

```
var imgData = new FormData();
imgData.append('uid', user_id);
imgData.append('o_img', $('input[name="imgs"]').get(0).files);
$.ajax({
            url : CDN_HOST + "index.php?action=upload",
            type: "POST",
            data : imgData,
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
            {

                if(jqXHR.status == 200){


                    if(data.error == 'true'){

                       alert'(true'); 
                    }else 
                    if(data.error == 'false'){
                        alert('false')

                    }else{
                        alert(JSON.stringify(data));

                    }

                }else{
                    alert('Some error');
                }

            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {

                //$('html').html();
                $('html').html(jqXHR.responseText);
                //$('html').html(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));

            }
        });
```

my php codes are,

```
if($_POST["o_img"]){

        $_response = $_POST['o_img'];               

}
header('Content-Type: application/json');

echo json_encode($_response);
```

The response in json I am getting is "[object FileList]". If I use `$_FILES['o_img']`, I am getting undefined variable. Can anyone tell me how can I use jquery or javascript to get multiple files and send it to server via ajax post?

Thank you for your time in advance. :D

Comment: what browser did you use?

Comment: Mostly Google chrome.

Comment: You mean you need an ajax code on how to send multiple files via AJAX concurrently to a Web server from browser??

Comment: @prasun, I need someone to find my mistake or tell me how to attach multiple files in ajax codes. So answer of your question is kinda yes. Because I have tried a lot to find solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just use following  method to simplify your post method

```
 var formData = new FormData($("form#Form Id")[0]);   // Mention here your form ID
    function save_from() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/", // url goes here 
            data: formData,
            success: function(data) {
               //Your Code Goes here
            },
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        }); 
}
```

Sample Form

```
 <form action="" id="Form ID" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="imgs" multiple >   
      <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="save_from()" >   
 </form>
```

Comment: use latest jquery library file.

Comment: It is latest jquery library.